# Regular expression to find anything except the given condition of symbols

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to find anything except "Dx.y" where *x* ranges over 0–31 and *y* over 0–7 or "Ka.b" where *a* is 28 or 23 or 27 or 29 or 30 and *b* being 0-7 for 28 and only 7 for others, from a file using regular expression.

I have ended up with `(([kK]((28\.[0-7])|(23|27|29|30)\.7)))|([dD](([1-9]|[0-2][1-9]|3[0-1]))\.[0-7])`
but need a negation expression.

Comment: So what do you want to match in a given string?

Comment: Why do you need a negation? Just invert the result: find everything that does not match the expression.

Comment: Your expression won't match Dx.y when x is 0 or 10 (but will match 01-09). Try this instead for 0-31: `[0-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]`.

Comment: @Richard I was trying to do the same. could you please elaborate on the approach.

Comment: @groverboy nice catch. will do the changes.

Comment: Note: `[0-1]` is the same as `[01]`, just like `[1-2]` is the same as `[12]`.

Comment: To match lines not matching: `... if (!regex.IsMatch(line))`

Answer (score 1):

If you use [non-capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), you can use `Regex.Split()` which will then return all the substrings between the matches:

```
splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, @"(?:(?:[kK](?:(?:28\.[0-7])|(?:2[379]|30)\.7)))|(?:[dD](?:(?:[1-9]|[0-2][1-9]|3[0-1]))\.[0-7])");
```